# How to know My Apps is used X time or X days android?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to show user a dailog box for rate my app on net if he likes. This dialog will appear if user has used(Viewed) my app X time or if the app is in his device for x days?
.

> I can use SharedPreferences on my splash screen and count each time app run. But I am wondering what if user not finish by pressing home. In this case the app will not launch. So what the solution?

**I was thinking there may be a component for this,like IPhone AppRater. Please tell me if any.
Or let me know how to do this.**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about setting a counter (stored in `SharedPreferences`) in `onResume()` in your main activity?

And for the date, how about storing a date in `SharedPreferences` if the date is not already set also in the `onResume()`-method of your main activity?

And the check for displaying the Dialog-Box (linking into the market) I would also add to `onResume()`.

`onResume()` is only called if the user really sees your activity. Have a look here concerning the app lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle